# The best way to patch Oracle Rac One Node

Tags: oracle, rac, patching

what is the best way (best practice) to patch Oracle Rac One Node  (2 nodes - node1 and node2, every node has own database home and GRID home = 4 homes)? Thank you

System: Oracle Solaris 11
DB: Oracle 18.9

Answer (score 2):

I've supported One Node installs for something like 8 years now:

1. Make sure all databases are running on node 1.
2. Patch the GI and DB homes (GI, DB, OJVM, Java JDK, etc.) on node 2.
3. Relocate the databases from the unpatched node 1 to the patched node 2.
4. Run the post-install SQL scripts for each patch on each database on node 2.
5. Patch the GI and DB homes on node 1.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about opatchauto, if it will automatically relocate database intance to another node and bring it back after patching?

Comment: It may relocate away, indirectly, by shutting down GI, but it will not relocate the database back to the original node at the end. Assuming both nodes are provisioned with equal resources there would be no need to do so. I've seen patches break GI to where relocation doesn't work at all, so I believe it's better to relocate the database in a controlled way, as a separate manual step. If there's a problem with the relocation I would know before the patching process started and be able to deal with it. I wouldn't want the relocation to fail and then have opatchauto shut down GI anyway.

Comment: Yea, good point. Ok, i will use your process. Which command from Patch readme are you using?  This one: <GI_HOME>/OPatch/opatchauto apply <UNZIPPED_PATCH_LOCATION>/30899645? Will this command patch both GI home and Database home too?

Comment: I haven't worked with One Node 18c, so not sure if it will actually patch both homes. My experience with earlier versions (11g and 12c) is that it was supposed to, but generally did not for some reason and I had to patch the DB home, OJVM, and the Java JDK separately.